# PhoneGap 2.0.1 Dealloc

Tags: objective-c, cordova, memory-management

I setup a phonegap 2.0.1 project and noticed that it is using ARC. However im wondering if the MainViewController.m which is automatically created for you, that inherits CDVViewController is also run under ARC.

I have added a few properties to the MainViewController like:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString* errorJS;
```

And i am wondering If I need to use dealloc to release it, or weather this is already handeld as CDVViewController is run under ARC :S

Can anyone tell me if I still need to release my properties in MainViewController or not?

Answer (score 0):

ARC basically means that you don't have to add release calls because the compiler adds them for you - the binary output from an ARC enabled project (eg libcordova.a) isn't any different from one where the release calls were added manually.

The answer depends on whether or not your project is set to use ARC. I believe the template has ARC turned off by default.

If ARC is enabled, calling release will produce a compiler error. If ARC is disabled, not calling release will usually produce a warning when you run static analysis.